# Using a function on different parts of data

Tags: r, dataframe, grouping

Say I have a data like this:

```
Date:   Item:   x1:    x2:  
1-Jan   Dog     0.3    0.2  
2-Jan   Cat     0.3    0.4  
1-Jan   Dog     0.1    0.3  
2-Jan   Dog     0.1    0.3
```

I am using this formula:

```
euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
```

And I want my final result to look like this:

```
Date:  Item:   Distance:  
1-Jan  Dog       x  -> x1=(0.3, 0.2), x2=(0.1, 0.3)   
2-Jan  Cat       y  -> x1=0.3, x2=0.4   
2-Jan  Dog       z  -> x1=0.1, x2=0.3
```

How can I do this where `x,y,a` are from the formula stated above? 
And I cannot hardcore the Date and the Item has they constantly change depending on what data set I use.

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`:

```
df <- read.table(text = 
"Date   Item  x1    x2
1-Jan   Dog     0.3    0.2  
2-Jan   Cat     0.3    0.4  
1-Jan   Dog     0.1    0.3  
2-Jan   Dog     0.1    0.3 ", header = T)

library(data.table)
euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))
dt <- data.table(df)
res <- dt[,  .(distance = euc.dist(x1, x2)), by = .(Date, Item)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you re-write `euc.dist` as

```
euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt((x1 - x2) ^ 2)
```

you can do

```
split(euc.dist(df$x1, df$x2), list(df$Date, df$Item), T)
# $`2-Jan.Cat`
# [1] 0.1
# 
# $`1-Jan.Dog`
# [1] 0.1 0.2
# 
# $`2-Jan.Dog`
# [1] 0.2
```